# Retrieve Cookie Content

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying tof ind a way to retrieve the content of a cookie in javascript.

Let's assume that the cookie is named "Google"

and lets also assume content of this cookie is just "blah"

I've been looking online and all I find are complex functions, and what I was wondering if there is a simple one line such code that retreives the value of the content in a cookie'

such as -

```
var myCookie = cookie.content('Google');
```

I don't want long parsers to check for various cookies or if the cookies have multiple value or whatever..Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) has a very simple, but effective cookie script.

```
var Google = readCookie("Google"); // Google is now "blah"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a simple one-line solution but close!

```
var results = document.cookie.match ( '(^|;) ?' + cookiename + '=([^;]*)(;|$)' );
if ( results ) myCookie = decodeURIComponent(results[2] ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to parse the cookie jar yourself but it isn't that hard:

```
var name    = 'the_cookie_you_want';
var value   = null;
var cookies = document.cookie.split(/\s*;\s*/);
for(var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
    if(cookies[i].substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
        value = decodeURIComponent(cookies[i].substring(name.length + 1));
        break;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.cookie, or document.cookie.split(';') to get a full list of key/values.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript all cookies are stored in a single string. THe cookies are separated by a ;
A possible function to read cookies is:

```
function readCookie(myCookieName)
{
  if (document.cookie.length > 0)
  {
    var start = document.cookie.indexOf(myCookieName + "=");
    if (start != -1)
    {
      start = start + myCookieName.length + 1;
      var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";",start);
      if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
      return unescape(document.cookie.substring(start ,end ));
    }else{
      return "";
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```